# Java Web Start - Does it work with Android?

Tags: java, android, java-web-start

As the title says, is deploying/using applications through Java Web Start a viable option? I found a few posts online from years ago saying that the JavaME applications are only available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not an option. Android has an Application Store (called [Android Market](http://www.android.com/market/)) that serves a similar purpose: managing applications install, updates and versions... So, technically, you don't need **JWS**.

Comment: For this application, we're not looking to deploy it on any application store (only our own local LAN). Is there another viable alternative?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy it to a local WEBSERVER you own.

Comment: So you can just have the 'APK' file and have a link on the Android device to the webserver with the APK file, similar to what rosstheboss said? (We don't have an Android to play around with or any experience with the platform.... yet)

Comment: Yes, you can. But I don't know if it will work on EVERY Android device out there. Here's how you would do it on the G1: http://www.blogsdna.com/1939/how-to-install-non-market-apk-apps-on-google-android-g1-phone.htm

Comment: So our application would be a command with `adb install <Full Path to apk file><apk file name>` as an icon on the device?

Comment: Not sure about that. I think yes, but I must tell you that I've always use SDK or ANDROID MARKET to deploy my applications...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just host the .APK file locally on your lan on a webserver and allow people to download it from their browsers?

Comment: Simply because they are not signed with a source certificate on the Androif Market and phones will reject those external APKs by default (some phone vendors will even refuse all support if any APK has been installed not coming from the Android Market/ now renamed Google Play).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to get automatic updates like webstart is to use the android market. However, if you just want to deploy your app in your local lan, you can put the app as a link on an internal web server and have people navigate to it using the browser.