# Is it Possible to run JNLP files on android?

Tags: java, jnlp

I want to know if there is a way to start Java fat-clients via JNLP on my android.

With an app or a webapplication or maby convert it to an other file format - annything would help me.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please start with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you port the Java plugin ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Web Start - Does it work with Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873960/java-web-start-does-it-work-with-android)

Comment: If you controlled the software development in some manner, you could rewrite it to be a webapp (using Servlets an related technologies).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core virtual machine in Android is not a JVM but a DVM.  The Davlik virtual machine is a non-stack based virtual machine (it is register based) that can run Davlik byte code (similar to Java Bytecode, but with register based operations instead of stack based operations).

So, in general, JNLP would not be expected to work without some extra effort, as the binaries transmitted in an JNLP launch would contain Java bytecode and not Davlik instructions.

If you want this functionality to work, you would need to either intercept the JVM bytecode and cross compile it to Davlik bytecode (not sure if this has been done before, but google may be your friend).  Or, you would have to install a true JVM on the android platform (again not sure about this approach, but it gives you a starting point).

The confusion between both of these platforms come from that fact that the source code (the text you would write) is Java source code; however, the compilation process for both environments does not result in JVM bytecode, which is required for running on a Java platform.  This is one of the primary reasons that it's called a Davlik virtual machine, and not a Java one.